# Vie d'après vs après-vie vs vie d'après la mort?

Tags: vocabulaire

I saw that these seem to all be translations of "afterlife" - *la vie d'après, l'après-vie,* and *la vie d'après la mort*. Is there a difference in register or connotation between these? Are they just interchangeable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say the most common is "**la vie après la mort**" (without *d'*).

There is no connotation or register difference (death is death, after all).

I have never heard of "**après-vie**", and a quick search shows it apparently doesn't exist in traditional dictionaries (Larousse, Robert). "**Après-vie**" sounds like a literal translation of the English word "afterlife", and was used to translate the Stephen King novel that bears this title.

Both "**la vie d'après**" and "**la vie après la mort**" are commonly used and interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ety that *la vie après la mort* would be the most common translation for "afterlife", when that term refers to the fate of one specific person. I disagree about *la vie d’après* though - that would be life after any event (a change of jobs, a divorce, etc.), possibly including death, but that would be highly context-dependent.

Another common term that would be more appropriate in certain contexts is *l’au-delà* (literally: "the beyond"; the best translation would likely be "the afterworld"). It refers to a collective place where the souls of the deceased would go after death, without much detail about what happens there exactly; it could refer to the Christian paradise (*paradis*), the Greek Elysium (*Champs Élysées*), or other belief systems.

The register is almost the same; maybe "au-delà" is slightly more formal. It also has (to my ears) a more "mystical" aspect. For instance, if I were a psychic trying to fleece a gullible mourner, I would rather claim

> Je peux communiquer avec l’au-delà

> I can communicate with the afterworld

than

> Je peux communiquer avec les esprits des morts

> I can communicate with the spirits of the dead

because (in French at least) the latter claim sounds more specific / technical.